# CM synergy file merging

Tags: merge, synergy, commit-charge

I am using CM Synergy 6.4.3410 version
And each time i do a code change ,if some one else does check in on same file its nightmare 
We need to reconcile it and take latest version from server then manually do the merging and check in .
There is an option for merge in reconcile window,but it actually creates a parallel version.
I have found out that Synergy does not do a smart merge.Even though the changes done are in different lines of the file

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to merge.I think it was obvious